# Why's my Redux states' behavior very strange based off the outputs in the console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

Why's my redux behaving the way it is based off the console output?

The intention of my code is for the user to input text into 3 boxes which then gets stored in Redux states in `mapStateToProps`.

According to the outputs, the values of actions are mix and matched and changed up as you go through out.

Why's this happening?  If more information is needed, please let me know.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            idValue: '',
            authorValue: '',
            cityValue: ''
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.cityCodeReducerRedux(this.state.cityValue);
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(this.state.value);
        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(this.state.idValue);
        this.props.authorNameValueRedux(this.state.authorValue);

        if(this.state.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter the value and then click submit" );
        } else {
            alert("Article saved " + "\n" + this.state.value + "\n" + "Id value " + this.state.idValue);
        }
    }

    handleStoryText = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleAuthor = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({authorValue: event.target.value});
    }

    handleCityValue = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({cityValue: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input value={this.state.cityValue} onChange={this.handleCityValue} placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input value={this.state.authorValue} onChange={this.handleAuthor} placeholder="author name" />
                        <textarea value={this.state.storyTextValue} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue,
        authorNameValue: state.authorNameValue.authorNameValue,
        cityCodeValue: state.cityCodeValue.cityCodeValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value}),
        authorNameValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.AUTHOR_NAME, value}),
        cityCodeReducerRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.CITY_CODE_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

Here's `AuthorNameReducer`:

```
import * as actionType from './actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    authorNameValue: ''
};

const AuthorNameReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("AuthorNameReducer => " + action.value);
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.AUTHOR_NAME:
            return {
                ...state,
                authorNameValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default AuthorNameReducer;
```

Here's output in the console:

```
CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => undefined
CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => undefined
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => undefined
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => undefined
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => undefined
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => undefined
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => undefined
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => undefined

CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => undefined
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => undefined
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => undefined
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => undefined

CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => cc
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => cc
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => cc
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => cc

CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => someStory
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => someStory
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => someStory
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => someStory

CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => 
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => 
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => 
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => 

CityCodeReducer.js:8 CityCodeReducer => someName
ArticleIdReducer.js:8 ArticleIdReducer => someName
AuthorNameReducer.js:8 AuthorNameReducer => someName
StoryTextReducer.js:8 StoryTextReducer => someName
```

Comment: Can you also add actions data.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta this is the action data.  These outputs are a result of  `console.log(action.data);`

Comment: what are the events that you did that resulted this output console?

Comment: @marouanekadiri I've included `AuthorNameReducer` in my original post.  All my other reducers are identical (besides their action types of course).

Comment: when did you click the submit button based on the output console?

Comment: @marouanekadiri I clicked the submit button right when I'm done putting input into the 3 boxes

Comment: you clicked once and resulted all this output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180901/discussion-between-sp92-and-marouane-kadiri).